# Get duration of each word in an audio file

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, audacity, aubio

Is it possible to get an approximate duration of each word in an audio file? The closest thing (for audio files from youtube videos) is to download the captions file as an `srt`. The `srt` will then have the duration for each sentence in the video.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow get the duration for each word in a sentence. Maybe not accurate but something around that ?

Comment: What's the connection to `python`?
As for the question: words are delimited by periods of quiet. Search for those intervals with only the background/ambient noise level. Anything between those are words.

Comment: Unless you have some extra information, it's a non-trivial task. There are some libraries which can provide you with detection or regions of speech vs. non-speech, aka speech activity detection, but that's only a starting point since it will not give you boundaries between words.\

Comment: @boardrider: In a natural speech, there is no pause between most words.

Comment: @ItamarKatz can you please point out such libraries (that detect regions of speech). That might be a starting point as you said.

Comment: It depends on what language/platform you use. Look for "voice activity detection" on google as a starting point

Comment: Difficult to answer your question without knowing what format your audio file uses.